# How to define a single action to handle all http GET requests that come to this controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

Here is the route definition:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{*data}",
            defaults: new { data= RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now, in the product controller, I have an action defined like this:

```
public string Get(string data="")
{
    return "value";
}
```

I test the `http-get` with the following URL

```
api/product/   
api/product/apple
```

both are working

But, if i use this URL

```
api/product/?p=5
```

it will throw out an exception

```
No action was found on the `controller` 'product' that matches the request.
```

i understand that i can define another action like this to resolve the problem

```
public string Get(int p,string data="")
{
    return "value";
}
```

But, that won't work for me, because the parameters on the `url` are unpredictable, either the name of the parameters or the value of the parameters.

So, my question is

Is there a way to define a single action to handle all the `http-get` requests that come to this controller no matter what kind of query string is used in the URL?

Comment: What happens when you do `api/product?p=5`? I cant say I have ever seen a URL that has a / followed directly by a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the Get with the WebAPI:

```
public string Get(int p) {}
public string Get(string data) {}
```

Although this excludes the case where you pass no parameters, from what I understand of your scenario, either method should be applied (either the name or the value) and so this should be fine.